# Load data for Blade component in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm looking for a way of loading data for a Blade component *each* time it's used. I'm sure I've seen it around but I can't seem to find the "right" way.

To clarify:
I have a couple of Blade *views* that all include the same Blade *component*. Instead of loading the data in each of the *views'* controllers, I'd like to separate the *component's* data. This way I can't forget to pass the varible to the *view*, etc.

Comment: I think you are talking about view composers https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers

Comment: Is this dynamic or static data? If it's static, you could just load a global set of data either in your config or by using composer "files" array to boot it up globally. If it's dynamic, view composers are the correct choice. If you really want to do it in a slick way and paste your components wherever you want, you can also look at using Vue components since they are supported out of the box with Laravel. You could load the data with AJAX in the mounted() function of the Vue component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the `boot` method of `providers/AppServiceProvider.php` you can use view composer just like below:

```
\View::composer('*',function($view){
        $model = YourModel::all(); //or any eloquent method or where clause you to use to fetch the data
        $view->with('anyName'=> $model);
 });
```

The `*` means that this data would be available to all views or you can specify some specific routes for which the data would be available. for more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) is the reference.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use view composers or share a data for each view you can read more
[here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)